# How to assign a varaible containg spaces to another variable in KSH

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting, ksh

I am writing a shell script to read the input file and process the contents of the file line by line.
I was planning to store each line to an array and process the array later as shown below.

```
#--------------------------------
# Global Variable
file_path="NULL"
set -A array_statements
#--------------------------------
readFileIntoArray()
{
    while IFS= read -r line
    do
        echo "$line"
        array_statements[${#array_statements[*]}+1]="$line"
    done <"$file_path"
}
printTheArray()
{
    for i in ${array_statements[@]}; do 
        echo $i
    done
}
main()
{
    file_path=$1
    readFileIntoArray
    printTheArray
}
main "$@"
```

The line contains spaces between the words as `Hello World How Are You?`. When I execute the script, and print the content of the array_statements, the output is

```
Hello
World
How
Are
You?
```

How do I assign the variable value which contains spaces to another variable or pass the varaible which contains spaces to another function in `KSH`.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable

Comment: Actually, I can't reproduce the symptom with the code you posted.

Comment: Are you using KSH?

Comment: Of course, though it's not my preferred shell.

Comment: Oh I think I know what's wrong.  You are probably calling `readFileIntoArray` incorrectly. Can you show us that part of the code?

Comment: Demo: https://pastebin.com/psTKAyiP

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: Yup, you're missing the quotes, like I told you in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest route forward is probably to scrap your current code and refactor it.

```
array_statements=()
while read -r line; do
    array_statements+=("$line")
done <"$1"
printf "%s\n" "${array_statements[@]}"
```

With the code simplified this much, it probably doesn't make much sense to keep anything encapsulated in a separate function.

Notice in particular how missing the quotes around `${array_statements[@]}` will break them up into one happy crazy string, losing any array element boundaries.

Comment: Collecting your data into an array is very frequently an antipattern. If you don't absolutely need random access, simply processing a single line at a time is going to be vastly more elegant and efficient.